# Product Url Redirect to Home Page Issue Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, url-rewrite

My configurable product redirecting to home page. I have removed the .html from Product URL Suffix and it works fine.

Now concern is if i open my configurable product then it redirect to home page. but if i put the .html as suffix in URL then only it works. My rest of the product works fine without .html in the URL.

- xyz.com/milwaukee-tools-203 - Not working
- xyz.com/milwaukee-tools-203.html - Working

I tried reindex and checked the URL_Rewrite table too. But it did not work.
Can anyone help?

Please check the below screenshots for more information.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I would check to troubleshoot the Magento configurable products redirecting to the home page when you remove .html from the URL suffix:

- Make sure you have cleared all caches after changing the Product URL Suffix setting. The cache can store redirects that need to be cleared.
- Check for any extension conflicts that may be interfering with URL rewrites on configurables. Try disabling third party extensions to isolate the issue.
- Look for customizations to the product view controller. Removing .html can sometimes reveal core code bugs.
- Review your Nginx/Apache URL rewrite rules - you may need to update rules for clean URLs without .html.
- Enable Magento developer mode and check system.log for errors when accessing the URLs without .html.
- Re-run the "Generate URL rewrites" tool under Marketing -> SEO & Search to rebuild rewrites.
- As a test, try setting the configurable product URL key to something other than the product name/ID.

Usually issues like this come down to a caching, extension conflict or web server configuration problem. Hope these methods help you in finding your solution.